# How does a two prong to three prong power adapter get the extra ground pin?

Tags: ground

In my understanding, the two prong adapter plug have hot and neutral wires but not ground wire. And the three prong adapter plug have hot neutral and ground wire. So how does the two prong to three prong power adapter just makes a ground wire?

Comment: No magic. There is no ground, third pin is not connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In The U.S. some of them have a fork or ring terminal sticking out or on a short wire that you are supposed to put under the outlet cover mounting screw. This provides a ground as long as the outlet box is grounded. [This link](https://acworks.com/blogs/ac-works-connector/2-3-prong-adapter-and-outlet-safety) shows one mounted on an outlet as well as some additional information regarding safety.

Other ones just omit the ground and make it so you can plug a three prong pug into a 2 prong outlet, disregarding safety.

You can use a [receptacle tester](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Power-Gear-3-Wire-Receptacle-Tester-50542/206212329) to verify if the adapter is actually getting a ground.

I don't know if other countries that use different outlet styles have something similar, you would have to check that for each country.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter just allows a three prong plug to plug into a two prong socket. It does not create a ground connection.